# Getting started with "Enhance PHP"

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am looking to incorporate a testing framework into a project I am building and came across [Enhance PHP](https://github.com/Enhance-PHP/Enhance-PHP/wiki) which I like but I am having some difficulty finding relevant information on-line since "enhance php" is such a commonly used phrase.

Has anyone worked with this framework that might be able to point me toward some helpful guide?  Have you worked with a unit test framework that you think is amazingly better?

Thanks in advance.

In response to Gotzofter, this is the class to be tested:

```
<?php
include_once('EnhanceTestFramework.php');

class ExampleClass
{
    private $OtherClass;

    function __construct($mock = null)
    {
        if ($mock == null)
            $this->OtherClass = new OtherExampleClass();
        else
            $this->OtherClass = $mock;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        return $this->OtherClass->getSomething(1, 'Arg2');
    }
}

class OtherExampleClass
{
    public function getSomething()
    {
        return "Something";
    }
}

class ExampleClassTests extends \Enhance\TestFixture
{
    public function setUp() 
    {
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
    }

    public function verifyWithAMock() 
    {
        $mock = \Enhance\MockFactory::createMock('OtherExampleClass');
        $mock->addExpectation(
            \Enhance\Expect::method('getSomething')
                ->with(1, 'Arg2')
                ->returns('Something')
                ->times(1)
            );
        $target = new ExampleClass($mock);
        $result = $target->doSomething();
        \Enhance\Assert::areIdentical("Something", $result);

        $mock->verifyExpectations();
    }
}

\Enhance\Core::runTests();
```

look at my constructor for ExampleClass.

Because enhance-php's site example injects the $mock object by calling new ExampleClass($mock), I am forced to change my ExampleClass constructor to handle a $mock as an input parameter.

Do I have to handle this for all classes that I want to subject to unit testing with the framework?

Thanks.

Comment: [enhance-php.com](http://www.enhance-php.com) contains a [Quick Start Guide](http://www.enhance-php.com/Content/Quick-Start-Guide/) and it also looks like they have [decent documentation on all the major features](http://www.enhance-php.com/Content/Documentation/). What exactly are you looking for beyond that?

Comment: [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de) is the defacto unit testing framework. TBH I've never heard of Enhance (don't take that is a cheap shoot, just being honest).

Comment: @Colin - Perhaps I'm just not understanding the Mock usage.  Following the instructions in that guide I am not getting the results I expect.  I'll add some code to the original post

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
function __construct()
{
   $this->OtherClass = new OtherExampleClass;
}
```

Should be:

```
function __construct($otherClass)
{
   $this->OtherClass = $otherClass;
}
```

Your mock is never injected at this point in your test:

```
   $target = new ExampleClass($mock);
```

Comment: I edited the original post.  Is that what you meant by your answer?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly do a constructor in which you have a default object creation. Just stay with standard **Dependency Injection**

Also, the `something` method has parameters in your test, but it is not implemented.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to figure out.  What IS the standard Dependency Injection..?  The examples on enhance PHP's tutorial don't show the entire picture and the above code is the only way that I have been able to get the tests to work.

Comment: @baiano - this article might help with Dependency Injection in PHP: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201112/Blog/Dependency-Injection-In-PHP/

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would recommend no matter what testing framework you are using is type-hinting against the expected class, or interface.

```
<?php
class ExampleClass
{
  private $OtherClass;  // OtherClass instance

  public function __construct(OtherClass $OtherClass=null)
  {
      // ...
  }
}
```

I'm no di expert, but I don't see the problem in letting each class call *new* if an instance isn't provided for a particular dependency.  You could also of course take the approach where you use setter methods to configure dependencies.

```
<?php
class class ExampleClass
{
  private $OtherClass;  // OtherClass instance

  public function setOtherClass(OtherClass $OtherClass)
  {
    $this->OtherClass = $OtherClass;
  }
}
```

It is lame that the **ExampleClass** in the sample code doesn't even define the **doSomething** method from the **ExampleDependencyClassTests**, but if I understand correctly it looks like **Enhance PHP** is not forcing you to take a particular style of dependency injection.  You can write the test class however you want, so for example if you took the setter method approach I mentioned above, you could change the example mock code to

```
<?php
class ExampleDependencyClassTests extends \Enhance\TestFixture
{
    public function verifyWithAMock() 
    {
        $mock = \Enhance\MockFactory::createMock('ExampleDependencyClass');
        $mock->addExpectation(
            \Enhance\Expect::method('getSomething')
            ->with(1, 'Arg2')
            ->returns('Something')
            ->times(1)
        );
        $target = new ExampleClass();
        $target->setExampleDependencyClass($mock);
        $result = $target->doSomething();
        $mock->verifyExpectations();
    }
}
```

Of course it would probly make sense to make the appropriate revisions to the **ExampleClass**!

```
<?php
class ExampleClass
{
    private $ExampleDependencyClass;

    public function addTwoNumbers($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }

    public function setExampleDependencyClass(
        ExampleDependencyClass $ExampleDependecyClass
    ) {
        $this->ExampleDependecyClass = $ExampleDependecyClass;
    }

    public function doSomething($someArg)
    {
        return 'Something';
    }
}
```

I've worked with **PHPUnit** quite a bit, and honestly you'll have to face the same challenges with *Mocks* there.  My 2 cents, try to model your tests without *Mocks* if possible ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on NetTuts titled [Testing Your PHP Codebase With Enhance PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/testing-your-php-codebase-with-enhancephp/), which will definitely help you to get started.

And there is a [Quick Start Guide on Enhance PHP](https://github.com/Enhance-PHP/Enhance-PHP/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

Comment: I opened an issue on The Enhance-php Github repo regarding a bug in the enhance-php-code: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: get_parent_class(): Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be an object or a valid class name, bool given in /Users/thome/Enhance-PHP/EnhanceTestFramework.php on line 603`. Thanks anyway for your work.